# How to find out the response time in sumo logic for a http request

Tags: logging, latency, response-time, sumologic

I have an application which contains akka http endpoints integrated with sumo logic. Each request has a trace ID. and Now I want to see write query on sumo logic to retrieve the trace ID for a request which has response time > 5 seconds. How to find out response time for a request in sumo ? Can be this be calculated/fetched in sumo, without logging it explicitly ?

Comment: Are you sending the response times to Sumo Logic?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. Sumo Logic - analize just based on data which you provide to it. So if you don't calculate response time on server and explicitly sent to Sumo it has no way to know it. For this task 'new relic' is good as it is integrated in php and have access to this kind of info.